# Normalize JSON with pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I want to normalize a json using pandas. The json is like this:

```
    { "fromDate":"2021-05-18T23:59:59.656Z", "pageRows":1, "sessions":[ { "variables":[ "encriptado:true", "lastruleitemid:123456", "carterizadoderivado:false", "encryptionconfig:ThisIsAConfig", "webchatcountry:ES", "webchathosturi:https://www.website.com/", "ipaddress:120.22.22.222", "webchathostpagetitle:WebpageTitle", "webchathostdomain:www.webiste.com", "webchathosturl:https://www.website.com/", "transaccional:false", "webchathosthref:https://www.website.com/", "derivadofb:false", "lastrulebuilder:thisisatest@website.io-1201", "webid:QERTY" ], "sessionDate":"2021-05-18T23:59:59.656Z", "botMessages":2, "userHasTalked":"true", "topics":[ "First Topic", "Second Topic" ], "sessionId":"QYUIOPLHNM-05-18T23:59:59.656Z", "platformContactId":"MNLKJHYIO-4757252DOUQ6JFP67UUCT", "sessionMessages":[ { "creationTime":"2021-05-18T23:59:59.675Z", "messageType":"Buttons", "message":"THIS IS THE FIRst Messageelegirlo aqu\u00ed \ud83d\udc47", "msgFrom":"bot", "imagesUrls":null, "audiosUrls":null, "videosUrls":null, "filesUrls":null, "ruleName":null, "operator":null, "queue":"Queue1" }, { "creationTime":"2021-05-18T23:59:59.672Z", "messageType":"Text", "message":"Hi This is the seconds message\n\u00a0\nCu\u00e9ntame \u00bfEn qu\u00e9", "msgFrom":"bot", "imagesUrls":null, "audiosUrls":null, "videosUrls":null, "filesUrls":null, "ruleName":null, "operator":null, "queue":"General" } ], "queues":[ "Queue1", "General" ], "customerId":"2737228328", "userMessages":2, "operatorMessages":0, "sessionMessagesQty":2, "sessionStartingCause":"Organic", "channelId":"wus8s22-webchat-null-838483", "conversation":"https://go.website.com/#/chats/UIOOWUIWUSU" } ], "toDate":"2021-05-18T23:59:59.656Z", "hasMore":false }
```

And I would like to end with a table like this in a dataframe:

```
                                 -------------from sessions---------------  -----from sessionMessages--------------------------------------------------
fromDate                pageRows sessionID                      customerId  creationTime message                                               msgFrom    
2021-05-18T23:59:59.656Z    1   QYUIOPLHNM-05-18T23:59:59.656Z  2737228328  2021-05-18T23:59:59.675Z    THIS    IS THE FIRst Message….         bot    
2021-05-18T23:59:59.656Z    1   QYUIOPLHNM-05-18T23:59:59.656Z  2737228328  2021-05-18T23:59:59.672Z    Hi    This is the seconds message…     bot
```

So far, I've been able to load only part of this, using the following:

```
pd.json_normalize(
    json_file, 
    record_path = ['sessions'], 
    meta=[
        'fromDate','pagerows'
    ], errors='ignore')
```

But when I try to add nested data, I get an error:

```
pd.json_normalize(
    json_file, 
    record_path = ['sessions'], 
    meta=[
        'fromDate','pagerows'
        ['sessions','sessionID']
    ], errors='ignore')   
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How should I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: My impression is that your records are located in `sessions.sessionMessages`, so you need `record_path=['sessions', 'sessionMessages']`?

Comment: With that I get the messages... But I still need to get the data from the upper level.

Comment: Have you provided the respective `meta` coordinates?

Comment: Thanks.. that worked:    normalized_messages=pd.json_normalize(
    json_file, 
    record_path=['sessions', 'sessionMessages'],
    meta=[
        ['sessions','sessionId'],
        ['sessions','customerId'],
        ],
    errors='ignore')